# Export UML diagrams from Entreprise Architect to an OCL tool (USE or OCLE)

Tags: uml, ocl

I have some diagrams made on Enterprise Architect and i want to export them to an OCL tool
"USE" or "OCLE".I tried the option export and converted the diagrams to a xml extension 
but it doesen't work on the OCL tool. How can i do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. [RTFM](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/useocl/index.php?title=Quick_Tour#2._USE_Specifications) ;-)

> a possible extension to USE would be the import of an XMI file created by a CASE tool

Comment: Well it is possible 
I exported the actors, associations and so one to OCLE

Comment: You just have to create a use case for example if you made a use case diagram in EA and drag the components to it